# Modifying the function count to return zero for strings and zero for numbers

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm writing a function that can input strings, numbers, arrays, Java Collections and Maps. The constraints are the output for both strings and numbers should be zero.

The Clojure function count does everything I need, except handle the constraints. So, I thought to use an if statement to test if the input is a string or a number. Returning zero if the test is true, and using count otherwise. I have workable code for either case, but do not know how to combine the two. Moreover, I am not sure the most efficient way to set up the testing in this case.

```
  (defn Swanson [a]
        (if (string? a) 0
        (count a)))

  (defn Propello [b]
        (if (instance? Number b) 0
        (count b)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clarity is more important than efficiency (and it almost always is), then I'd use cond here:

```
(cond
  (string? a) 0
  (instance? Number a) 0
  :default (count a))
```

There's the possibility that what you really want is "the count if it's countable, otherwise 0". In that case, the 'seq' function can help

```
(if (seq a) (count a) 0)
```

And if you *actually* care about performance, doing it with protocols should let you buy into more JVM optimizations in principle. But profile before and after to make sure!

```
(defprotocol SwansonPropello
  (swanson-propello [a]))

(extend-protocol SwansonPropello
  clojure.lang.ISeq
  (swanson-propello [a] (count a))

  clojure.lang.Seqable
  (swanson-propello [a] (count a))

  Object
  (swanson-propello [_] 0))
```

Comment: I realized that strings are seqable, so the second two examples won't solve your specific problem. cond is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
(defn swanson-propello [x]
  (if (or (string? x)
          (number? x))
    0
    (count x)))
```

`or` is the most fundamental form for this type of combining. Its docstring describes it well:

```
Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
returns a logical true value, or returns that value and doesn't
evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns the
value of the last expression. (or) returns nil.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#(if (string? %)
   0
   (count %))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn alex
  [obj]
  (cond
    (string? obj) 0
    (number? obj) 0
    :otherwise (count obj)))
```